# definition proof w/ integers a,b<0

Tags: real-analysis

We are required to utilize definitions to prove this; they are as follows.

If $a<0$, then there exists some $x$ such that $a+x=0$.

Using this fact, we must prove that if $a,b<0$, then $ab>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have $\begin{cases}a+A=0\\b+B=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{align}AB
&=AB+0\\
&=AB+(a+A)(b+B)\\
&=AB+ab+AB+aB+bA\\
&=ab+(AB+aB)+(AB+bA)\\
&=ab+B(a+A)+A(b+B)\\
&=ab+0+0\\
&=ab\end{align}$

And I guess we have to use $A>0,B>0$ and then $AB>0$, which are not explicitly given in your wording but I don't see how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

" If $a < 0$ , then there exist some $x$ such that $a+x = 0$ " 
With this statement, $x$ is a reflection of $a$ then $x = (-1)×a$, that's because $a < 0$ means that $a$ is negative

If ${a,b} \in Z$ with ${a,b} < 0$

*The product of two negative number produces a positive number*, then $ab$ must be positive, which implies $ab > 0$

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that we can use $x,y>0 \implies xy>0$ and $0x=0$ for all $x$.
Suppose $a<0$ and $c>0$. Then for some $x>0$, $a+x=0$, hence $0=(a+x)c=ac+cx$. Since $cx>0$, $ac<0$.

Now suppose $a,b<0$, $a+x=0$. Then $0=(a+x)b=ab+xb$, and since $xb<0$, $ab>0$.