# How to prove it? If $a < 0, b > 0$ prove $ab < 0$.

Tags: inequality

**Proof**

$a < 0$ implies $-a > 0$, by hypothesis $b > 0$, therefore $(-a) (b) > 0$. Concluding that
$$-ab > 0 \implies ab < 0$$

Comment: Please formulate explicite;ly your question, and the context: where do $a,b$ live? Which axioms are assumed for $<?$

Comment: Note you can use this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635367/399263 to show that if $A=-a$ and $B=-b$ then $AB=ab$ with only using the $+$ sign. It allows to give substance to the "rule of signs" for the product.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct. You might want to mention that you are using(I am hoping you are) the definition of less than. By defintion, $a < b$ if and only if $b - a > 0$. Therefore, if $a < 0$, then $0 - a = - a < 0$. Then I am assuming you have proven that if $a < b$, then $a - b < 0$. If you haven't, this is easy to prove from the definitions and by contradiction.

Proof: If $a < b$, then $b - a > 0$ by definition. Suppose that $a - b > 0$. This implies that $b < a$. Which is a contradiction.

This helps your argument that if $-ab > 0$, then $ab < 0$. Because if $-ab > 0$, then $0 - (-ab) = ab < 0$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.